# JEE Transactional: where to specify dontRollbackOn / rollbackOn

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, transactions, cdi, java-ee-7

I have a question regarding the usage of rollbackOn and dontRollbackOn of the JEE transactional annotation. I did some rearch however only found general information on the [topic](https://struberg.wordpress.com/2015/04/21/transaction-and-exception-handling-in-ejbs-and-javaee7-transactional/))

`@Transactional(dontRollbackOn = {SomeRuntimeException.class}`

**Where can/must I specify the annotations**? Two options make sense to me so which one is it?

1. In the class the RuntimeException occurs
2. The "sticky" approach - when the transaction is created (in my case with Requires_new) and once the transaction was annoted it will react accordingly doesn't matter when/where the exception occurs

I would really like the 2nd version since I create a new Transaction which is "handed down" through be business layer to the database related classes. A specific database method is used by two different business functions and only one wants the "dontRollbackOn" function.

However currently in my case (JBOSS 7 EAP, JEE7, Java 1.8) only version 1 works. I need to anotate the method where I do the actual DB query...

```
@Transactional(dontRollbackOn = {SomeRuntimeException.class}
public void doSomething(){
 ...
 Query query = this.getEntityManager().createQuery(...);
 query.setParameter(...);
 queryResult = query.getSingleResult();
}
```

Can somebody share some light on this?

Comment: No, we are using JBOSS 7 EAP Version which is JavaEE 7 (https://developers.redhat.com/products/eap/overview) Clarified that in the post...

Comment: Are you trying to deal with [javax. persistence.NoResultException](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/NoResultException.html) and [javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/NonUniqueResultException.html)? There's simpler ways of managing this,

Comment: What would be your simpler way? As written in the javadoc the current transaction won't be rolled back for these two: "This exception will not cause the current transaction, if one is active, to be marked for rollback." (But in my experience this is handled differently in different jee servers...) But my question was how it is done for any other RuntimeException...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you need to do it on the EJB method that throws the exception. Otherwise the exception propagation will mark the transaction for rollback at the method call boundary. So it is answer (1) from your post.

Some further advice:

The best way to deal with unexpected exceptions is to let them bubble out and deal with them somewhere near the UI boundary. As they are unexpected you don't normally want *any* transactions to commit because that will leave your application in an inconsistent state.

However, your sample code provides a case where exceptions may actually be expected. In this case you should deal with them in the originating method:

```
try {
    Query query = this.getEntityManager().createQuery(...);
    query.setParameter(...);
    queryResult = query.getSingleResult();    
    ...
} catch (NoResultException e) {
    // What are the business rules when NoResultException happens?
} catch (NonUniqueResultException e) {
    // What are the business rules when NonUniqueResultException happens?
}
```

If one or both are actually *unexpected* then paragraph one still applies.

Comment: Yes that might be the best way in most cases but not in ours. I explicitly don't want the transaction to be marked as "rollback" however that was the thing which happened. So I experimented with "dontrollback" but wasn't sure about its exact positioning. It would have been neat if a transaction could be annoted at a service class and not at the DB class level (presumes that the same transaction is used)....

Comment: Unfortunately you need to do it on the EJB method that throws the exception. Otherwise the exception propagation will mark the transaction for rollback at the method call boundary

Comment: Thank you - that was the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you are using EJB Stateless beans which come with transaction handling by default, you can control the transaction rollback using either `Context.setRollbackOnly()`(inject EJB context, and in your catch block, set it to rollback if you need), or use your custom Exception type, that you would throw from service methods, where you want rollback to happen. This exception needs to have `@ApplicationException(rollback=true)` annotation present. The second options is very handy and clean way how to handle transaction mechanism in EJB, as it is clear from the declaration of your bussiness method, whether it rolls back on error or not e.g. `public void handleRegistration() throws MyServiceException`. Whenever container encounters a service call, that results in your MyServiceException, it will roll back the current transaction(if present).

Transaction is also rolled back if you throw an instance of `RuntimeException`

More info can be found in a free ebook [Mastering EJB3](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1369778/Free-Book-Mastering-Enterprise-JavaBeans-30)

Comment: I think the OP is more interested in *not* rolling back the current transaction.

Comment: right, I should have clarified, that there are two approaches - container managed transactions(EJBs) and bean(user) managed transactions(`@Transacational`). Both are described in [Java EE tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/transactions003.htm). EJBs come with transaction handling by default(configurable via `@TransactionAttribute`), and unless you do one of the above mentioned means to trigger rollback, then all changes performed in transaction gets committed.